# Finding limits with vertical asymptotes algebraically

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

So I've been using Google an I can't find an answer. I'm supposed to find the following limit algebraically:

$$\lim_{x\to -3^-}\frac{x+2}{x+3}$$

I can tell this is a vertical asymptote through graphing and plugging in numbers, but how do I determine that the limit is without bounds using algebra?

Comment: As $x \to -3^-$, $x+3 \to 0^-$. So $\frac{-1}{0^-}=+\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x < -3 \iff x+3< 0 \text{ and } x+2< 0 \iff \frac{x+2}{x+3} >0$$
thus
$$\lim_{x\to -3^-}\frac{x+2}{x+3}= +\infty,$$
since $\lim_{x\to -3^-}x+2=-1$ and $\lim_{x\to -3^-}x+3=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped.